# Users are unable to login into Samba shares

Tags: ubuntu, security, samba, windows-10

I'll get the version numbers and hardware out of the way here;
I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian 9.6 Stretch headless, I have a 2tb USB drive that I'm using as the storage media, and I'm running Samba version 4.5.12-Debian.

As for the clients, they are all running Windows 10 1607 in either the Personal edition or LTSB edition flavors.

Here is my Samba config file;

```
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# Written for Bistack on Raspberry Pi



#======================= Global Settings =======================
[global]
## Core Networking Options ##
    netbios name        = Bistack
    workgroup       = Cadosphere
    encrypt passwords   = yes
    min protocol        = smb2

## Netbios Name Service Settings ##
    wins support        = yes
    dns proxy       = no

## Debugging/Accounting ##
    log file        = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    log level       = 1
    max log size        = 1000
    panic action        = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

## Authentication ##
    server role     = standalone server
    passdb backend      = tdbsam
    obey pam restrictions   = yes
    unix password sync  = no
    passwd program      = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat     = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    pam password change = yes
    map to guest        = bad user
    ntlm auth       = true
    security        = user  



#======================= Share Definitions =======================
## Core Samba shares and networked devices ##
[homes]
    comment     = Home Directories  
    browseable  = no
    read only   = yes
    create mask = 0700
    directory mask  = 0700
    valid users = %S

[profiles]
    comment     = Users profiles
    path        = /home/samba/profiles
    guest ok    = no
    browseable  = no
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask  = 0700

[printers]
    comment     = All Printers
    browseable  = no
    path        = /var/spool/samba
    printable   = yes
    guest ok    = no
    read only   = yes
    create mask = 0700

[print$]
    comment     = Pointer for Windows clients to find the proper Printer Drivers
    path        = /var/lib/samba/printers
    browseable  = yes
    read only   = yes
    guest ok    = no

## Multi-User General Shares ##
[cadosphere]
    comment     = Network folder for Cadosphere projects
    path        = /~/nas/cadosphere
    valid users = matt
    admin users = cadosphere
    read only   = no
    browseable  = yes
    public      = yes
    writeable   = yes

[shared]
    comment     = Network folder for anyone on the network
    path        = /~/nas/shared
    gues        = okay
    read ony    = no
    browseable  = yes
    public      = yes
    writeable   = yes

## Single-User Dedicated Shares ##
[matt]
    comment     = Matts network share
    path        = /~/nas/matt
    valid users = matt
    force user  = matt
    read only   = no
    browseable  = yes
    public      = yes
    writeable   = yes
```

On the windows clients all of the shares are shown, but when you go to access them, Samba asks for a password (as it should) and the user is unable to authenticate themselves and access their share(s). [When they try, they get an error saying that the location is unavailable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJGQt.png)

I have also set up a public share called `shared` and that works just as it should.

I used the command `sudo pdbedit -L` and that listed both users accounts that I have set up and added to Samba.

According to `smbstatus`, the only user account that ever connects to the server is called `nobody`.

I have tried reinstalling Samba, and Samba-common and worked through a couple answers on this forum.

Comment: are your user accounts active with valid passwords (they can be logged into on the Pi, they aren't requesting a password change)?  I've seen similar when pass changes were requested since Win doesn't play well with remote pass change via Samba (especially using "passwd chat" with "pam password change")

Comment: @Ruscal yes, the user accounts that are trying to log into the shares are valid, active accounts. As far as I can tell they are not requesting a password change.